# Probability distribution with reduced support close to uniform

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm looking at the following problem:

Let $X$ be a the discrete uniform random variable on the support $\mathcal{X} = \{0, 1, \dots, n\}$, and consider a subset $\mathcal{Y}\subseteq \mathcal{X}$. The goal is to find a probability measure over $\mathcal{Y}$ such that one still has a uniform representation of the numbers in $\mathcal{X}$ (if that makes sense), even though the support is reduced.

For example take $n=100$, but suppose $\mathcal{Y}=\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 100\}$. If one naively to take $p$ to be uniform over $\mathcal{Y}$, then more weight is put on small numbers, making it non-uniform over the original support $\mathcal{X}=\{0, \dots, 100\}$.

My current way of solving it (which is surely not the only one) is to solely impose that the expected value of the distribution should be the same as the uniform one, that is $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{n}{2}$. Since there are no other restriction, the problem becomes finding the [maximum entropy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution) given the first moment constraint $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{n}{2}$.

Would there be another better way to do so? Or maybe a less demanding way, since finding the maximum entropy distribution requires to solve a convex optimization problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your method can't work since you might not be able to enforce equality of the expectations. What if you take $\mathcal{Y} = \{1\}$?

Comment: I agree, and I realize I should have been more specific. My question is more about whether one can come up with a way to do what I described approximately. In your example for sure one is restricted so any approximation would be extremely poor, but in general there might exist a scheme which work well when $\mathcal{Y}​$ is not too restricted.

Comment: Hi: your methid is reasonable but you may want to put a variance constraint in also because just satisfying the mean might not result in a good set of numbers since the mean is not robust to outliers. or maybe use the median instead of the mean ?

Comment: Another issue is that the goal seems underspecified to me. For example, what if instead of your example I chose the support $\mathcal{Y} = \{1,3,5,7,9,100\}$. If you make 100 more likely in order to avoid "overrepresenting" small numbers, you now have an overrepresentation of even numbers. Even worse, if you change the distribution, suddenly the number, say 1, is _underrepresented_. So I'm not sure this is salvageable unless you put restrictions on what subcollections you want to consider